# how generate and write stream data to s3 on the fly with python and boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

How to write dynamically generated data on the fly to `S3` by chunks with `python` and `boto3`?

I want to realise something like this:

```py
from io import BytesIO
from boto3 import ???

s3_opened_stream = ???

for i in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'x', 'y', 'z']:
  data = (i*1000).decode('utf-8')
  s3_opened_stream.append_chunk(BytesIO(data))

# OR something like

with ??? as s3_opened_stream:
  for i in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'x', 'y', 'z']:
    data = (i*1000).decode('utf-8')
    s3_opened_stream.append_chunk(BytesIO(data))
```

And expeect to see resulted file like:

```
aaaaaa......
bbbbbb......
cccccc......
.....
```

Where every line will be appended to same S3 object.

I checked examples in the internet and everywhere data was generated fully at first step and after generating uploaded to S3.

I tried to use these examples like:

```
from io import BytesIO
from boto3.s3.transfer import TransferConfig
from boto3 import resource

config = TransferConfig(
    # set possible lower size to force multipart-upload in any case
    multipart_threshold=1, 
    max_concurrency=1,
    multipart_chunksize=5242880,
    use_threads=False
)

bucket = resource(
    service_name='s3',
    region_name=params['region_name'],
    endpoint_url=params['endpoint_url'],
    aws_access_key_id=params['aws_access_key_id'],
    aws_secret_access_key=params['aws_secret_access_key']
).Bucket(params['bucket_name'])

with BytesIO() as one_chunk:
    for line in lines:
       # write new line inside one_chunk
       ...
    
       # write data to object
       bucket.upload_fileobj(one_chunk, obj_path, Config=config, Callback=None)
    
       # clear chunk data to release RAM
       one_chunk.truncate(0)
```

But `upload_fileobj` everytime rewrites object with new line instead of append to it.

In other words I want to open S3 object in append mode (like `with open('path', mode='a')`) and append lines that will be generated in loop. Because actual resulted file is very big and can't be stored in RAM memory in full

Comment: `boto3` alone can't do this, you will need a library such as -> https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open

Comment: @gold_cy Thank you for the link. I saw `smart_open`, but I still believe that `upload_fileobj` (for example) may be extended or overridden without using third-party libraries to achieve behaviour that I need...

Comment: what's wrong with using a third-party library, you already are using one by using `boto3`

Comment: @gold_cy No serious reason... Just don't like add dependencies. And little bit curious how S3 stream transfer working under the hood

Comment: @gold_cy there are some aws environments where third-party libraries cause issues, like within an MWAA worker for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I give up to try understand `boto3` code. It is pretty complicated and classes are not simply extendable.

Looks like [`smart_open`](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open) is most easy solution:

I checked this code with ~`4GB` input file

```py
from boto3 import Session
from smart_open import open

c = Session(
    aws_access_key_id=id,
    aws_secret_access_key=key
).client('s3', endpoint_url='http://minio.local:9000')  # I use minio for testing

read_path="bucket_name/in.csv"
write_path="bucket_name/out.csv"
with open(f"s3://{read_path}", mode='rb', transport_params={'client': c}) as fr:
    with open(f"s3://{write_path}", mode='wb', transport_params={'client': c}) as fw:
        for line in fr:
            fw.write(line)
```

And it is working like a charm. Memory usage was about ~`350MB` at peak. (Checked by [`htop`](https://www.deonsworld.co.za/2012/12/20/understanding-and-using-htop-monitor-system-resources/)'s `RES` value)

> RES: How much physical RAM the process is using, measured in kilobytes.

> RES stands for the resident size, which is an accurate representation of how much actual physical memory a process is consuming. (This also corresponds directly to the %MEM column)